# How to store second (time) as a constant on ios?

Tags: constants, ios7.1

Is this the bad way to store a second value on header file?

```
static const int waitForDurationToRemove = 2.9;
```

I use this value on another class.

```
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: waitForDurationToRemove];
```

This is not working properly. Is this problem with int?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int is for integer, you should use a `NSTimeInterval` instead. As per the documentation.